# Highlight find results by default in Netbeans 7.0

Tags: netbeans-6.9, netbeans-7

Netbeans 6.8 and 6.9 highlighted all instances of a text search result in every open file be default.  Toggling the highlight search did not affect the default setting - results were always highlighted unless highlighting was selected off after a search initiated.

[image]

But Netbeans 7.0 remembers the toggle highlight setting between searches.  So after every text search I must either tolerate the highlighting from my last search or toggle highlighting off until I am ready to do a search again, then toggle highlighting back on.  Then toggle back off again when I am done.

Is there any way to make Netbeans 7.0 behave like Netbeans 6.8/ 6.9 regarding the toggle highlight feature?  I want Netbeans to always default to highlight search results after a new search is initiated, regardless of actions during the previous search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans 7.1 changed this behavior so it now works like it did in Netbeans 6.9 and previous versions.  Apparently I was not the only person who did not like the change for 7.0.